# Did not find out the right tag for parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8b9c5bd97e71> in <module>()
     48     runtime = movie.find('span', class_='runtime').text if movie.p.find('span', class_='runtime') else ''
     49     movie_runtime.append(runtime)
---> 50     director = movie.find('p').find('a').text
     51     movie_director.append(director)
     52 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I was parsing director attribute from IMDB website: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=horror&title_type=feature&explore=genres

My code for parsing is

```
movie_director = []
movies = page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'lister-item-content'})
for movie in movies:
    director = [p.a.text for p in movie.find_all('p', attrs={'class' : ""})]
    movie_director.append(director)
```

I know the error in this line because I got the error after adding this line. Most probably I did not select the right tag for parsing.

Any suggestion for selecting right tag will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: can you post the code you've tried ?

Comment: Take a look again at the image of the website's html you included. The anchor tag (`a`) you are trying to access (the one highlighted in red) does not belong to the paragraph tag (you highlighted in green).

Answer (score 1):

because director element has no class value you can select nearest element that has class value `(.text-muted)` then select next element using `+` then to get only first link use `a:nth-child(1)`

```
directors = soup.select('.text-muted + p a:nth-child(1)')
for d in directors:
    print(d.text, d['href'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link = [p.a.text for p in 
        soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class' : ""})]
print(link)

['Mike P. Nelson', 'Kevin Lewis', 'Alain Darborg', 'Rose Glass', 'Christopher Landon', 'Sam Raimi', 'Ari Aster', 'Castille Landon', 'Lenny Abrahamson', 'Zack Snyder', 'Jordan Peele', 'Justin Benson', 'Dave Franco', 'Roseanne Liang', 'Olivia Wilde', 'Andy Serkis', 'Stanley Kubrick', 'Robert Eggers', 'M. Night Shyamalan', 'Ari Aster', 'Rob Schmidt', 'Gerard Bush', 'Brandon Cronenberg', 'Josh Boone', 'Mike Flanagan', 'Leigh Whannell', 'Jon Turteltaub', 'Ridley Scott', 'Robert Eggers', 'Matt Bettinelli-Olpin', 'Aneesh Chaganty', 'Keola Racela', 'Craig Zobel', 'Jonathan Milott', 'Andy Muschietti', 'Walter Salles', 'John Krasinski', 'John Krasinski', 'Robert Zemeckis', 'Johannes Roberts', 'Jordan Peele', 'Steven Kostanski', 'David Prior', 'Robert Rodriguez', 'Galder Gaztelu-Urrutia', 'Michael Chaves', 'William Eubank', 'Patrick Lussier', 'Egor Abramenko', 'George Mihalka']
```

you need to add the `class` for `p` tag as there are may `paragraph` tags. within that `p` tag we've an `a` tag next to it. so we can do `p.a` extracts the `a` tag with `href` and text[Director Name]. Since we need just the text `p.a.text` will do that
Update:

```
movies = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'lister-item-content'})
movie_director=[i.find('p',{'class':''}) for i in movies]
[i.a.text for i in movie_director]
```

your `movie_director` is a list which have list of director's name

Comment: you need to extract just the `directors name` or other items related to movie..

Comment: I updated the code in my question. I got the same error again. I am scraping for other attributes as well. But within the crew members I scrap only for director.

Comment: The updated code you have posted is not working.`AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: I used `find_all`

Comment: sorry about that ..updated...iterating over list..so

Answer (score 0):

All the directors have `_dr_` in their href so, provided you pass an User-Agent header you can use an attribute = value css selector with contains operator to target that substring in the href attributes; which is nice and concise. This should return the correct number of directors as there can be more than 1 per film.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=horror&title_type=feature&explore=genres', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml') # 'html.parser' 
directors = [i.text for i in soup.select("[href*='_dr_']")]
print(directors)
```